# Hibernate and Com_show_warnings == Com_select in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate

When looking into `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` on my MySQL it is showing that `Com_select` and `Com_show_warnings` are more or less equal. That means that Hibernate executes `SHOW WARNINGS` for each query it executes. Is there a way to disable this? Google did not help :/

Comment: What's logger library do you used? Could you see [this post](https://plumbr.eu/blog/io/how-we-accidentally-doubled-our-jdbc-traffic-with-hibernate) and try to change `org.hibernate` logging level to error and see whether `SHOW WARNING` still executed or not?

Comment: Log4J. I have already `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info` - which should be enough to eliminate these calls. They still happen though.

Comment: Did you try `log4j.logger.org.hibernate=error` and see if the problem still exist? Maybe put your `log4j.properties` and `hibernate.cfg.xml` or `persistence.xml` will help others identify your actual problem.

Comment: Well it seems `error` level really helped, if you answer the question, I will award you the bounty.

Comment: Hi @Vojtěch, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in [this blog post](https://plumbr.eu/blog/io/how-we-accidentally-doubled-our-jdbc-traffic-with-hibernate), hibernate force us to use `SHOW WARNINGS` when we set log level from `warn` or above.

This is the part of that code:

```
public void handleAndClearWarnings(
        Connection connection,
        WarningHandler handler) {
    try {
        /* This is the real method that causing the problem. */
        walkWarnings( connection.getWarnings(), handler );
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle) {
        // workaround for WebLogic
        LOG.debug( "could not log warnings", sqle );
    }
    try {
        // Sybase fail if we don't do that, sigh...
        connection.clearWarnings();
    }
    catch (SQLException sqle) {
        LOG.debug( "could not clear warnings", sqle );
    }
}
```

Thus, to avoid `walkWarnings()` method get executed, you could try to change `log4j.logger.org.hibernate` level to `error`.